# Showcasing Ionic Apps For a Portfolio Without Publishing Them to App Stores

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I have a few Ionic apps that I made that I want to add to my portfolio site for potential employers to check out. However, I would like to upload them somewhere so that when a visitor clicks on my link, it will take them to a website showcasing my app. I don't want to push my apps to the actual stores, but still make them publicly viewable. Is this possible to do with an Ionic application?

I understand that Ionic View exists, but I have to send out email permissions for people to try my app (from what I know). I'd rather my apps just be uploaded somewhere and be easily accessible through links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, with Ionic View you can just share its ID number (see the image below) and anyone with this number will be able to download your app (via Ionic View) without you having to send them the invitation.

[image]

Your second option, but maybe a bit harder to do, is to host your application on your server. So, you would take all the content from the `www` folder and simply put it on your server in a certain folder and your app would then be accessible from the web as well. What I usually do is I create an iPhone image and create an `iframe` in which I then show the Ionic app. I won't go into details here, there are similar questions that cover this particular topic already.

Anyways, hope this helps, and clearly for the least effort the Ionic View seems like the best option.

Comment: Can you clarify how your first method will work? I posted my app in account1 and logged into a different browser with account2 and visited the link https://apps.ionic.io/app/<appID>  but it just directs me to a dashboard with no mention of the app. I'm assuming you mean that they have to type out the id in their Ionic View app on their phone?

Comment: Yes, correct, the first method involves the usage of Ionic View.